# trigger function in UserControl after Button Click in MainWindow (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have a `UserControl` inside of my `MainWindow`. I want to trigger function `updateView()` inside of my `UserControl` after clicking on my `button` in my `MainWindow`.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

***MainWindow.xaml***

```
<local :UserControl></local>
<Button x:Name="btn_start" Click="btn_start_Click"></Button>
```

***MainWindow.xaml.cs***

```
private void btn_start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  //trigger updateView in UserControl.xaml.cs
}
```

***UserControl.xaml.cs***

```
private void updateView() {
  //start something in UserControl, this is irrelevant
}
```

Comment: Assign x:Name of the UserControl, make updateView a public method and call it from btn_start_Click.

Comment: What exactly does updateView do? Why isn't it an icommand property on a viewmodel which is the datacontext of the window?

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest way is to assign an instance using `x:Name` like this

```
<local:UserControl x:Name="yourusercontrolinstance"/>
```

And then in usercontrol the function's access specifier must be public, then you can invoke that method via the instance.

```
yourusercontrolinstance.updateView();
```

Comment: x:Name does not "*assign an instance*". It generates a field in the MainWindow class that holds on object reference to the UserControl instance that is created during parsing the XAML. This instance also exists without x:Name, it is just not so easily accessible.